# Open in a new tab using javascript - unusual circumstances, cannot access the <a> code

Tags: javascript, html, css

I create event registration websites in a system called Cvent. It is a system specifically designed to allow non-coders to create a registration website where attendees/invitees can come and register, for example, for a convention, or a meeting, or an incentive trip. Cvent also allows advanced coding in order to customize the event site. I code advanced sites.There are times that I am unable to access some coding because it was created within Cvent - think of it is a widget. In a nutshell, I have some links to other reference sites that was coded by Cvent and it did not include  target="_blank" within the hyperlink. Is there any script that I can add to a page that will force any existing hyperlink to open in a new tab? Maybe a couple screenshots will help explain my situation....

I am entering in the name and the url to be linked to the name, which Cvent codes for me in the background...

[image]

On the front end of the site, it looks like this
screenshot of the front end of this link

[image]

When an attendee/invitee clicks on that link, it opens up in this same tab. I need it to open in a new tab. Is there any type of script that will force all hyperlinks to open in a new tab?

I do now how to code javascript so I have not tried anything. I've searched but not really finding anything that helps. It's a pretty specific problem because of the restrictions I'm coding under.

Answer (score -2):

If you are using  then put  target='_blank'

Or for javascript use window.open()

Hope it will help you,

Thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using `target='blank'` as it has some security flaws. You can read about them here. https://www.tutorialdocs.com/article/html-opener-blank.html

Comment: Please read the entire question... I cannot access the <a> part of the code. I'm working in a system that did the hyperlink for me. I need to find if there is a way to force a link  that I cannot access to open in an new tab.

Comment: i guess i answered, before u finished editing. so i guess u can write some javascript code . https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/open-external-links-in-new-window/

Comment: use below code in document.ready function                                                           
  $('a').each(function() {
   var a = new RegExp('/' + window.location.host + '/');
   if(!a.test(this.href)) {
       $(this).click(function(event) {
           event.preventDefault();
           event.stopPropagation();
           window.open(this.href, '_blank');
       });
   }
});

Comment: Yes. I can add code on top of existing, including script. It just varies. Not everything is accepted, though, so it's a lot of trial and error in Cvent.